# Are all ions stable?

Tags: ions, stability

My science teacher says that all ions are stable, which seems wrong to me.

For example $\ce{He^{-1}}$ is an unstable ion of helium, and although it might not exist in the real world, it is still technically an ion of helium. Is it right?

Comment: Of course there are plenty of unstable ions. But maybe your teacher wanted to say something different. He might have thought of a given group of ions, for a given application...

Comment: I have a feeling the point was all ionised atoms are stable by themselves. As you can see, it's not true for anions.

Comment: Even calling a positively charged ion 'stable' ignores the fact that it is quite happy to grab spare electrons...

Comment: +1 for not just swallowing a sweeping statement without thinking through its limitations. // $\ce{He+}$ isn't "stable" either. // The statement would be true for ionic salts. So in NaCl, the sodium and chlorine atoms don't flip-flop between ions and uncharged atoms.

Comment: In a way, everything that exists is stable.

Comment: I will point out that the fact that the negative ion of helium is metastable for long enough is important for tandem accelerators - one can do Rutherford Backscattering with helium since the metastable lifetime is long enough to get to the terminal to then be stripped to being a positive ion. So, indeed, the negative ion of helium 'exists' at various times around the world.

Comment: Stable relative to what? You need some reference point to compare energies. And there better be the same amount of matter present (no comparing energies of neutral atoms and ions).

Comment: Your teacher made an awfully strange comment if not given within a greater context. Presumably it was meant that ions of a soluble salt are stable in solution (they don't tend to recombine to form the solid).